# Php Get Email Attachment

Tags: php, forms, email, email-attachments

i have a form where i have an input file to place an attachment. It happens that all the data i have in the form i want to send by email. However, before i do that, i redirect all the data inputed to another php page and receive it with get.

So my first question is, how can i get the content of the attachment in other php page by get?

After that, after i verify all the data in the new php page, i pretend to send it by email. I plan to use this code:

```
    //define the receiver of the email 
$to = 'myemail@something.com'; 
//define the subject of the email 
$subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 
//create a boundary string. It must be unique 
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com"; 
//add boundary string and mime type specification 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.zip'))); 
//define the body of the message. 
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2> 
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
$message = ob_get_clean(); 
//send the email 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

But i have a doubt, where there is "attachment.zip" what should i put? The variable that will get the data of the attachment on this new php page?

Thanks in advance!

Forgetting the part above:

this is my declaration and submit button on the form:

```
<form id="formElem" name="formElem" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">

<button name='enviar_candidatura' id='enviar_candidatura' value='enviar_candidatura' onclick='return false;' type='submit'>
```

when i click on the button above, i enter on the following jquery function:

```
$('#enviar_candidatura').bind('click',function(){

    var conta_Duplicates;
    conta_Duplicates=dadosImportantes();
    //alert("Deu");
    var preenchimentoForm=true;
    //alert("Contasssss"+conta1);
    //var eventos=$countEventos;
    var eventos=conta_Duplicates[2];
    //alert("Wiggins"+eventos);
    //var empregos=$countEmpregos;
    var empregos=conta_Duplicates[1];
    //var cursos=$countCursos;
    var cursos=conta_Duplicates[0];

    //alert($countEmpregos);
    if($('#formElem').data('errors')){
        preenchimentoForm=false;

        dadosFormularios(form, preenchimentoForm, cursos, empregos, eventos);
        return false;
    }
    else{
        dadosFormularios(form, preenchimentoForm, cursos, empregos, eventos);
    }
}
```

That's in this function i'm having difficult, because if i'm right, i should have a var here assigned to the form element so that i can pass her to the function "dadosFormularios".

Once inside the dadosFormularios(...), it's there i want to call the

```
form.action = 'index.php?pagina=candidaturasB&'+ qstringA;
```

to redirect to the php page where i will send the email with the attachment.

Hope i was clear and sorry for some variables in a foreign language, hope it's not a problem.

Comment: From where do you get the file? Upload?

Comment: It's a form where i have and input type="file" there. The user select there the file from his Pc that he wants to sent.
So what i pretend in therms of code is to receive that information on another php page to sent the file specified by the user to an email.
Is that possbile?

Comment: You can write a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form you are completing needs to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and needs to have `method="post"` for upload to work.

like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)";>
    <input type="file" name="filename" />
    // ...........
</form>
```

After that in your send mail you can get the file with `$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']`, notice that `filename` has to be same as input's name:

```
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])));
```

for function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkForm(form){
        // process fieds
        return checkNextFunction(form);
    }

    function checkNextFunction(form){
         form.action = 'myurl.php';
         return true;
    }
</script>
```

Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BK4ZK/).

Comment: And i don't need to add anything to the url when i send the data from the first php page to the other where i will send the email?

Just use this?
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])));

Comment: but i have the action like this: action="" because i don't have the url for the new php page Mihai. When i click on the submit button of the form, before i redirect to the second php page i pass through a javascript function that is called at the click of the submit button and the function is the one who redirects me for the new page. Will that be a problem?

Comment: You cannot do that, you cannot redirect from javascript a file upload. It must be done like I told you.

Comment: But i need to pass through the function i mentioned because of other things, that's the problem :/

Comment: Then you cannot do it. Sorry. What does that function do, maybe we can modify it ?

Comment: well, it's a jquery function that basically works as a client side validation, and after that redirects to a javascript function that, since i have fields on the form that can be duplicated, triplicated and more, appends all the data to the url that goes to the new page.

Comment: What if i, before click on the submit insert the attachment in a table of the database and send the id in the url to get him in the other page?
Is that possible to do?

Comment: That jQuery function has to do something else like: `$('#id_form').submit();`, modify your form add `id="id_form"` and add full URL in form. No you still need to upload.

Comment: Mihai sorry to causing you so much trouble. I'm not explaining well.
When i click "submit" on the form i call a jquery function. There, i verify if all the fields have data and how many where duplicated or triplicated. After that, i jump to another function, this time a javascript one where i generate the url that goes with all the that and so, i use window.location.href to redirect to the new php page with all the data on the url. So, the option you gave me on the last comment will still work? If yes, can you give me an example? I didn't understand the last part. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Yes, you can do functions in function, check updated code. I cannot answer anymore on this subject. I gave you the solution. Best of luck. If you need other info try adding a new question about your new problems.

Comment: Just another question please,
if i have id="formElem" and in the last javascript function i use:
formElem.action = 'index.php?page=.....with the data
it will work?

Comment: yes, you must have `method="post"` and your script should work with no problems

Comment: I must be missing something, the formElem.action = 'index.php?page... is not working. When i click it does nothing, i even tried document.formElem.action :/

Comment: I put the code there on JSFiddle but it happens the same. No sign of errors i think.
Anyway, you mentioned this on a comment above $('#id_form').submit();, i dind't put it, just use what i said 2 comments ago, is that ok?

Comment: Wait a minute, i guess i forgot something. You always pass this argument on the funcions you give as example: (form) is that the form id? I'm not passing that, should I?

Comment: You need to pass form element, not id. `onsubmit="return checkForm(this)";` - `this` will be the form element

Comment: In my case is a little different: 
I don't have onsubmit what i have is:
<button name='send_cand' id='send_cand' value='send_cand' onclick='return false;' type='submit'>Send Data</button>

That i call on jquery with: $('#send_cand').bind('click',function(){
...

Can i add onsubmit="return checkForm(this)"; without problems?
Sorry for all this questions, but i'm really having difficult with this :/

Comment: you don't really have to ad that, you just need to capture the form element in a jQuery variable.

Comment: And that would have to be done inside this function right?
$('#send_cand').bind('click',function(){
since i have this code on the button:
<button name='send_cand' id='send_cand' value='send_cand' onclick='return false;' type='submit'>Send Data</button>

Comment: Yes. Please. I told you. Please post another question. I do not have time to chat.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Mihai, but can't you tell how can i assign the form element to a var inside this jquery function:

$('#send_cand').bind('click',function(){

so that i can pass her through the next functions until the form.action?

I'm really stuck here :/

Comment: If I don't see any scripts I cannot tell you what to do.

Comment: Done, please check the main post.

Comment: Meet me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15947/discussion-between-mihai-iorga-and-user1511579)